# Remove all href of page by simple html dom

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

i am fetching the page by simple html parser or simple_html_dom.php. I am getting only images h1 h2 h3 and p elements in the page and i want to remove href attributes from the anchor tags. But getting error.
According to official documentation the the syntax is..

Remove a attribute, set it's value as null!

```
   $e->href = null;
```

But I am getting error.
 Here is my code.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lifehacker.com/');
 $html=$html->find('h1 , h2 , h3  ,img, p');
 $html->a["href"]=null;
 foreach($html as $elements){
 echo $elements.'<br>';
 }
```

i want to remove href from every element. Means only link appear but user should not be able to open it or target it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Will it give you the wanted result when you only check for the anchors?

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if (isset($element->href)) {
        $element->href = null;
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: i am still not getting the perfect result. when the page is loaded and i click on heading of post it navigates to the href. i want to disable this navigation...

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you check if it works for you?

Comment: Thanks my friend.. if you have any kind of resource of help for simple html parser please mention here...

Comment: Of course, maybe you can use [this page](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/PHP_HTML_DOM_parser/PHPHTMLDOMParser.cc_09-07-2011.php3)